# How to change Wishlist button color once product added to Wishlist using controller

Tags: controllers, wishlist, magento2.4.1

How to change the wishlist button color once the products added to the wishlist.I am getting an error while using a controller.

Ref:

1)https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/256570/57334

2)https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/266125/57334 **(Controller)**

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255810

Comment: namespace Heart\List\Controller\Index; error. my path : app\code\Heart\List\Controller\Index.php code : https://codeshare.io/G8EXJB

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: after update the folder name List to Listcolor, the issue solved

Comment: I need this -> https://snipboard.io/I36yhQ.jpg

Comment: My workout : 1) app\code\Heart\Listcolor\registration.php code- https://codeshare.io/G6P4Vg 2) app\code\Heart\Listcolor\etc\module.xml code- https://codeshare.io/adXeOy 3) app\code\Heart\Listcolor\Controller\Index.php code- https://codeshare.io/2pbA84 4) and added script to app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml end of the file.

Comment: I need if the customer added products to wishlist the icon color should change and don't redirect to the wishlist landing page.

Comment: do you want this on the listing page or detail page? and  you missing the routes.xml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119622/discussion-between-zus-and-hafiz-arslan).

Comment: Can you pls join the chat, i have attached a screenshot

Comment: Hi hafiz, the class included, can you pls join chat, thanks.

Comment: Can you pls help me with how to update the image bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a custom controller to change Wishlist button(icon) color once the product added to Wishlist.

> app/code/vendor/module/Controller/Index/Wishlist.php

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
            $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $data = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection()->getData();

        return $result->setData(['status' => 200, 'items' => $data]);
    }
}
```

> app/code/vendor/module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="customwishlist" id="customwishlist">
            <module name="Devcrew_Wishlistcustom"/>
        </route>
    </router>
```

> Add the following Script in theme's **list.phtml** or **wishlist.phtml** Depend upon Theme :

```
 <script>
    require(['jquery'], function($){
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('customwishlist/index/wishlist') ?>',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    var wislistAddesCheckData = data;
    var itemLenth = wislistAddesCheckData.items.length;
    for(i=0;i<itemLenth; i++){
    var wislistAddedProductId = wislistAddesCheckData.items[i].product_id;
    $(".product-id-"+wislistAddedProductId).attr('src','<?php echo $img; ?>');
    }
    }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

> Add this class in wishlist Div or Image:

```
class="product-id-<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getId();?>"
```

Comment: Thank you, working perfectly.

Comment: hi hafiz, i am working on a google business review, i  got the response but every time i manually copy paste the Authorization key, how to handle this case, i tried lot i need some expert guidance, this is my first google API task, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/339482/57334